# Show that if $f$ and $g$ are both convex and $g$ decreasing, then $g \circ f$ is concave

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Show that if $f$ and $g$ are both convex and $g$ decreasing, then $g \circ f$ is concave given the necessary conditions that $g \circ f$ is defined.
I tried using the basic definition of convex functions using the inequality but it doesn't quite pan out.
I'm starting to doubt that this result is true but can't come up with an easy counterexample.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f:x \mapsto x^2$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$, and $g:x \mapsto 1/x $ is convex and decreasing on the same interval.

But $x\mapsto g\circ f(x) = 1/x^2$ is still convex.

Comment: As simple as a counterexample can be, thanks you very much!